# How to export az network public-ip list output to a csv?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cli, jmespath, az

How do I go about exporting the output to a csv? Thanks in advance

```
az network public-ip list --query "[].{name: name, address: ipAddress}"
```

Here's the output:

```
[
  { address: "23.101.140.39", name: foo},
  { address: "23.101.140.38", name: bar},
]
```

I tried `az network public-ip list --query "[].{name: name, address: ipAddress}" | export-csv -path "c:\ips.csv"` but this outputs some metadata instead of actual data. Is there a way to unwind that array of documents using JMESPath query? That might fix the issue I am facing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Export-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7) is `Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility`, it converts objects into a series of comma-separated value (CSV) strings. Since you could accept the PowerShell commands, you can easily achieve your requirements with Az PowerShell [Get-AzPublicIpAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Az.Network/Get-AzPublicIpAddress?view=azps-4.5.0). It's not recommended to mix the az CLI commands with PowerShell commands.

```
Get-AzPublicIpAddress | Select-Object Name,IpAddress | Export-Csv -Path "c:\ips.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

[image]

**Edit**

For az cli, you can use it like this with PowerShell,

```
((az network public-ip list --query "[].{name: name, address: ipAddress}") | ConvertFrom-Json) |  Export-Csv -path "c:\ips.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why mixing az cli and pwsh is not recommended? Could you please link me to a documentation?

Comment: For clarity, Bash scripts are used inline. Per my experience, the az cli used in PowerShell  has a bit differences(like Quoting issues) from the az cli in Bash. see [Tips for using Azure CLI effectively](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/use-cli-effectively?view=azure-cli-latest)